# No internet connection on the VPSs created using Virtualizor (KVM)

Tags: ip, kvm-virtualization

I installed Virtualizor and KVM virtualization to be able to host multiple VPS servers on my dedicated server.

My server provider said that my IP information are:

- Netmask: 255.255.255.255
- Gateway: 10.255.255.1

Before completing.. my dedicated server have Ubuntu 16.04 x64 installed.

So, after I knew my IP information, I added them in `/etc/network/interfaces` then restarted the `networking` service.

I also restarted the `virtnetwork` service which was installed by Virtualizor.

So after doing that, I can see that there's still internet access on the dedicated server.

But now, I assigned another IPv4 address to my dedicated server and my provider said that the new IP address information are the same as the dedicated server's main IP address information.

So now, I created a VPS server on my Virtualizor panel, assigned the new IP address to it, and it booted well!

**But (the problem)..** I can't SSH into the VPS server from my PC, and also when I accessed the VNC console of the VPS server I noticed that there's no internet connection on the VPS server :/

I think that the problem is that the gateway `10.255.255.1` is in a local (internal) format.. but I searched everywhere about a way to calculate the Gateway address but I can't find any.

The VPS server IP is: `93.90.194.72`, and the dedicated server IP is `93.90.194.156`

Comment: What did your hosting provider say when you asked them this question?

Comment: @MichaelHampton - They said that the gateway of all the IPs hosted by them is `10.255.255.1` only.

Comment: I mean when you asked them specifically about setting up virtualization. This setup is common enough that they should already have a knowledge base article about it, but I can't find one on Fasthosts' web site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - They said that virtualization is possible on their dedicated servers, but they refused to help :/

Comment: I can only suggest you make a bridged network, if Virtualizor can even do that. Otherwise go find a better provider, like OVH, Hetzner, Online.net, and many others.